# Check for file on FTP server [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I'm making a program and I need to check if there is a file on a server and If the file doesn't exist then create it.  If the file does exist than display it in a textbox

something like

```
If (Not File.Exists("ftp://mysite.com/thisfile.txt")) Then
File.CreateText("ftp://mysite.com/thisfile.txt")
End If

If File.Exists("ftp://mysite.com/thisfile.txt") Then
TextBox1.text = mysite.com/thisfile.txt
End If
```

thanks - mas

edit - The file will be named off of a textbox

Comment: What happens if two clients connected to this server do this at the same time...

Comment: @Hans Passant they enter a code so technicly, it would be TextBox1.text & ".txt"